# SvgPictures.asset not filling the container

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I was trying to use SvgPictures.asset as a background for my container, yet it doesnt fill it, the black part is the container itself with Colors.black while the orange part is the svg
Any idea why is it like this?

```
Container(
                        height: 100,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          'assets/images/title-bg.svg',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
```

[image: SVGPicture]

Also... if no height is set at the container, it becomes like this
[SVGPicture without height set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6yE5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the thing... turns out, when I received the SVG file, there is some whitespace outside of the normal shown image there, hence, creating the empty spaces, I used an external software to deleted it and it is showing perfectly now...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you using an alignment, and I don't think there is any wrong with the fit property, its best to use

```
fit: BoxFit.fill
```

And if it doesn't work I think there is a problem with the image's dimensions, I can clearly see the image doesn't have enough height and width to fill the container.

So the probable solutions maybe-
Try removing alignment,
Try another image with appropriate dimensions,
Try using jpg or png rather than SVG images.

Comment: Hmm... the image source I have is in SVG so I want to use it without changing it.
And if I use BoxFit.fill this is the result... which is kinda the same as BoxFit.cover

Comment: Could you send me the original svg image link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y38gsjcpjgnohie/title-bg.svg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fit` parameters for your case. It can be `BoxFit.cover` or `fit: BoxFit.fill`

```dart
SvgPicture.asset(
  "",
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

You can find more about [`BoxFit`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit.html)

Comment: I was already using BoxFit.cover though...

Answer (score 0):

- You can use BoxFit.fill parameters.

  `SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/title-bg.svg',fit: BoxFit.fill,),`

Comment: The results is almost the same, it just doesnt fill up the container (black area)